# NoMethodError when returning an array in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, forms

I'm building an app for a restaurant and I have a form where I add meals to an order and a price field gets dynamically updated depending on what dishes and how many of them you pick.

To do that I built a nested form (I think that doesn't matter anyway) which looks as follows:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.collection_select(0, @dishes.collect{ |dish| [dish.name, :data => {:description => dish.price}]}, :name, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "meal-select"})
  = f.select :quantity, options_for_select((1..10))
  = f.text_field(:price, disabled: true)
  = link_to_remove_association "X", f
```

The thing that bugs me is the `collection_select`. As you can see, I am returning an array with a name and a `data-description` which goes to the HTML tag. Based on the `data-description`, my price field gets updated.

However, I have no idea what method I should choose to extract the name of a dish. As you can see I tried `0` since name of the dish is always first in the array. I have also tried `:first`, `:name` but none of those works! The error I get is:

```
"NoMethodError in Orders#new 
undefined method '0' for #Meal:0x007fe4eb8e26c8"
```

or when I use `:name`

```
undefined method `name' for ["Zupa z Krewetkami", {:data=>
{:description=>17.0}}]:Array
```

Naturally, it points to:

```
= f.collection_select(0, @dishes.collect{ |dish| [dish.name, :data => {:description => dish.price}]}, :name, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "meal-select"})
```

I don't think the problem lies in my controller but, I'll show it just in case:

```
def new
  @dishes = Dish.all
  @order = current_user.orders.build
end
```

I tried looking for an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316217/nomethoderror-in-ordersnew) but as you can see the problem has not been solved and it was slightly different than mine.

To sum up - my question is what method I should use to extract name of the dish from my array in `collection_select`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use collection_select

```
...
= f.collection_select :meal_select, @dishes, :name, :price, {include_blank: true}, {class: "meal-select"}
...
```

For more details [see the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).

**Use below approach**

```
options_for_select( [['First', 1, {:'data-price' => 20}],
                     ['Second', 2, {:'data-price' => 30}]] )


= f.select :meal_select, options_for_select(@dishes.collect{ |dish| [dish.name, dish.price,{'data-description' => dish.price}]}), :class => 'meal-select'
```

Comment: Hey krishnar, thanks for your reply. Your example is a basic use of collection_select. In my case, however, I want to include `data-description` in the HTML tag for each select option. Hence, I'm using `@dishes.collect`.
It is returning an array with a name and a price. My problem is that I don't know what method I should use to extract the name of the dish. As I said, this is crucial in my case because I'm using `data-description` to dynamically pass the value to my 'price field'

Comment: = f.select :meal_select, options_for_select(@dishes.collect{ |dish| [dish.name, dish.price,{'data-description' => dish.price}]}), :class => 'meal-select'

Comment: I changed it to

    = f.select :name, options_for_select(@dishes.collect{ |dish| [dish.name, dish.price,{'data-description' => dish.price}]}), :class => 'meal-select'

I don't know why but it's working. Thanks!